# How to get distinct data from left joined result?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables `servers` and `server_group`. I tried `left join` but my problem is two times server-group id and name getting. I need the server-group id and name distinct. Please help me.

**left join**

```
SELECT sg.id, sg.name, s.servers_id, s.title
FROM server_group sg
    LEFT JOIN servers s ON sg.id = s.group_id
```

**server_group**

```
id name
1  google   
2  yahoo
3  msn
```

**servers**

```
servers_id| title| name|
2           yahoo   yahoo
2           yahoo   yahoo
3           msn     msn
```

**Result of my query is**

```
id| name |  servers_id|  title|
2   yahoo     2          yahoo
2   yahoo     2          yahoo
3   msn       3          msn
1   google    null       null
```

I need id and name distinct. In my listing page I need to get both table results. When I click on server_group servers details will show.[image: Please click here for sample view]

Comment: seriously what is your output I couldn't understand mate

Comment: How on earth can you have 2 servers with the same servers_id?

Comment: Add the expected result as text!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT sg.id, sg.name, s.servers_id, s.title 
FROM server_group sg 
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT servers_id, title
   FROM servers
) s ON sg.id = s.servers_id
```

So, instead of joining to `servers` table, you need to join to a derived table that contains only *distinct* values.